# Updates records more than one time on laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update values in laravel. I have a userupdate profile api which I can update the values first time with given parameters and their values but 2nd time when I update same values it gives me user profile does not exist.

My Code is :

```
  public function UpdateUserProfile(Request $request)
  {

    $id = $request->input('id');
    $client_gender = $request->input('client_gender');
    $client_age = $request->input('client_age');
    $client_weight = $request->input('client_weight');
    $client_height = $request->input('client_height');
    $client_dob = $request->input('client_dob');

   $profile= DB::table('clients')
        ->where('id',$id)
        ->update(['client_gender'=>$client_gender,'client_age'=>$client_age,'client_height'=>$client_height,'client_weight'=>$client_weight,'client_dob'=>$client_dob]);
    if($profile)
    {
        $resultArray = ['status' => 'true', 'message' => 'User profile updated Successfully!'];
        return Response::json( $resultArray, 200);
    }
        $resultArray = ['status' => 'false', 'message' => 'User profile does not exist!'];
        return Response::json($resultArray, 400);}
```

first time when I update the value it gives me the response like this:

```
  {
"status": "true",
"message": "User profile updated Successfully!"
  }
```

and when I hit the update request through a postman it gives a 400 Bad request and response is :

```
{
"status": "false",
"message": "User profile does not exist!"
}
```

Comment: what happens when you include `'id' => $id` within the `update( )` function?

Comment: it update with the given id suppose if id is 2 it will update records against id 2 but when i update again with id 2 without changing any parameter and values it gives me error which i display above.

Comment: is it possible that you could make a Client model to represent this db table?

Comment: yeah i added  a clients model instead of this db table but same response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend rewriting that function to look like the following; mostly because it reads better and uses the Model methods that are more commonly found in Laravel

```
public function UpdateUserProfile(Request $request)
{
    // this code fails if there is no client with this id
    $client = App\Client::findOrFail($request->id);

    // attach new values for all of the attributes
    $client->client_gender = $request->input('client_gender');
    $client->client_age = $request->input('client_age');
    $client->client_weight = $request->input('client_weight');
    $client->client_height = $request->input('client_height');
    $client->client_dob = $request->input('client_dob');

    // save
    $client->save();
    return ['status' => 'true', 'message' => 'User profile updated Successfully!'];
}
```